# Showing Invalid Date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I created a Javascript logic to retrieve date and time from some values.

initially i did was parsed the DateTime, convert it to string, then Split the string and retrieve the Date.

Like that i retrieved the time parsed, and atlast Joined all together(new Date + new Time).

I tried to convert it to date, now when i alert it then it says invalid Date. I want to display the newly created date just like this format.

var sampDate = new Date();
alert(sampDate);

Iam no good at explaining so iam uploading my code to fiddle and here also.

Please take a look at the JSFiddle. What i was done is below. Please point out what iam doing wrong with a detailed description. Any help will be very much appreciated.

JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/5csge/

```
    var date = 1745488627000;

    var parsedDate = new Date(parseInt(date, 10)).toString();

    var splitDate = parsedDate.split(" ");

    var currentMonth;

    switch (splitDate[1]) {
        case "Jan":
            currentMonth = 1;
            break;
        case "Feb":
            currentMonth = 2;
            break;
        case "Mar":
            currentMonth = 3;
            break;
        case "Apr":
            currentMonth = 4;
            break;
        case "May":
            currentMonth = 5;
            break;
        case "Jun":
            currentMonth = 6;
            break;
        case "Jul":
            currentMonth = 7;
            break;
        case "Aug":
            currentMonth = 8;
            break;
        case "Sep":
            currentMonth = 9;
            break;
        case "Oct":
            currentMonth = 10;
            break;
        case "Nov":
            currentMonth = 11;
            break;
        case "Dec":
            currentMonth = 12;
            break;
    }

    var time = -688627000;

    var parsedTime = new Date(parseInt(time, 10)).toString();

    var splitTime = parsedTime.split(" ");

    var convertedEndDate = new Date(splitDate[2] + "/" + currentMonth + "/" + splitDate[3] + " " + splitTime[4]);

    alert(convertedEndDate);

    var currentDate = new Date();
    alert(currentDate);
```

Comment: `date` is already a decimal number. `parseInt(date, 10)` will return the same value.

Comment: You know that the `Date` object has a `getMonth()` method?

Comment: What is your expected Date time format ?

Comment: You don't need to stringify and parse anything. All these methods are already implemented in a native Date object. Read more: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: The Date [*toString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.2) method is entirely implementation dependent. Once you have a Date object, use it to create a formatted date using [*getFullYear*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.10), [*getMonth*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.12) and [*getDate*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.14). Note that the month number is zero indexed so January is 0, December is 11.

Comment: @Navin : var currentDate = new Date();
    alert(currentDate);

Comment: @A1rPun : Thanks for denoting me that, damn. beginner's fault..!!

Comment: this constructor might be a bit, better that concating strings, _new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond);_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
var convertedEndDate = new Date(splitDate[2] + "/" + currentMonth +
                                   "/" + splitDate[3] + " " + splitTime[4]);
```

where you assume that `24/4/2025 00:42:53` can be passed as a parameter into a `Date()` object. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> **dateString**
>
> String value representing a date. The string should be in a format recognized by the Date.parse() method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps and also a version of ISO8601).

This obviously isn't ISO8601 format (that would start 2025-04-24), but it also doesn't appear to be in the format of an RFC282 timestamp either. In fact, you're better off NOT translating the month name back into a number; the following appears to work perfectly, replacing the `/` with spaces:

```
var convertedEndDate = new Date(splitDate[2] + " " + splitDate[1]
                                 + " " + splitDate[3] + " " + splitTime[4]);
```

Comment: Note that MDN is primarily for Mozilla implementations of JavaScript, not browsers in general. The only string that might be reliably parsed is the one specified in [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15), and even that one isn't.

Comment: voila. this is what i were looking for..!! :-) and thanks for the explanation Adrian.

Comment: @KRIZTE Pleasure to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

Use [New Date - setFullYear()](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp) and [setHours()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sethours.asp)

```
new Date()
setFullYear();
setHours();
```

[DEMO UPDATED](http://jsfiddle.net/5csge/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use date object and sets methods.
    D = new Date();
    D.setDay(12);
    D.setMonth(2);
when you make this, the date will continue intervally after scripte is executed

Comment: *setDay*? Surely not! :-)

Comment: For(i in d){alert(i);} will output all the methods availible in d object which is instance of Date()

Comment: *for..in* will iterate only over **enumerable** properties of an object and those on its `[[Prototype]]` chain. It will not list the built–in methods or properties as they are not enumerable. The definitive reference for Date objects is [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9), various browser vendors also have references, e.g. [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and [*MSDN*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t5580e8h(v=vs.100).aspx).